# How do I define a range through numeric value of a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have numeric variable `colNum` which contains numeric index of a column in a workSheet. How do I define a range, which includes correspondent column plus next column adjacent to it?

I.e. if `colNum = 3` then  the range should contain columns 3 and 4 entirely.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub UseKolumNumber()
    Dim r As Range, colNum As Long
    colNum = 3
    
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, colNum), Cells(1, colNum + 1)).EntireColumn
    MsgBox r.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub RangeFromColNumber()
  Dim colNum As Long, rngCols As Range
  colNum = 3
  Set rngCols = Range(cells(1, colNum).EntireColumn, cells(1, colNum + 1).EntireColumn)
  Debug.Print rngCols.Address
End Sub
```